# MongoDB/PyMongo: upsert array element

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have the following document:

```json
    {'software_house': 'k1',
     'client_id': '1234',

     'transactions': [
      {'antecedents': 12345,
       'consequents': '015896018',
       'antecedent support': 0.0030889166727954697},

      {'antecedents': '932696735',
       'consequents': '939605046',
       'antecedent support': 0.0012502757961314996}
      ...
                     ]}
```

In which key 'transactions' stores within an array 3 features, for each item.

I would like to update each item contained in the 'transactions' array, that matches with the same 'software_house', 'client_id', 'transactions.antecedents' and 'transactions.consequents'; and thus:

- Overwriting the element within the array if it does exist
- Appending a new value within 'transactions' if it doesn't

How could I achieve that using pymongo?

Comment: What's the mongo version are you using?

Comment: MongoDB 5.0.8 Enterprise @Gibbs

Comment: Great, you can achieve this using [$set aggregate update](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-set)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an update with aggregation pipeline. You can first `$filter` the element matched. Then `$setUnion` with the item you want to upsert

### PyMongo:

```py
db.collection.update_many(filter = {
  // the criteria you want to match outside array
  "software_house": "k1",
  "client_id": "1234"
},
update = [
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "transactions": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$transactions",
          "as": "t",
          "cond": {
            $not: {
              $and: [
                // the criteria you want to match in array
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$t.antecedents",
                    12345
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$t.consequents",
                    "015896018"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "transactions": {
        "$setUnion": [
          "$transactions",
          [
            {
              "antecedents": 12345,
              "consequents": "the entry you want to upsert",
              "antecedent support": -1
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

### Native MongoDB query:

```js
db.collection.update({
  // the criteria you want to match outside array
  "software_house": "k1",
  "client_id": "1234"
},
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "transactions": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$transactions",
          "as": "t",
          "cond": {
            $not: {
              $and: [
                // the criteria you want to match in array
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$t.antecedents",
                    12345
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$t.consequents",
                    "015896018"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "transactions": {
        "$setUnion": [
          "$transactions",
          [
            {
              "antecedents": 12345,
              "consequents": "the entry you want to upsert",
              "antecedent support": -1
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/g63ToiEuFi3) for your reference.

Comment: Thank you for your comment; would you mind updating it for PyMongo usage? Best

Comment: @AlessandroCeccarelli sorry my bad. I don't have a pymongo setup handy, but I tried to update the answer to use `update_many` according to this [doc](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=update#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_many). Please kindly help to see if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your kind feedback; it seems like it does not create a new document, in case the collection's empty. To reproduce it, you can simply run that code on a new empty collection. Thank you for your support

Comment: @AlessandroCeccarelli Have your tried adding `upsert: true` like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zhm7Zdlz_z1)? You may want to ask a separate new question for upserting on document level. This could be over the original scope of upserting at array field level. Blending the 2 questions together will make the question lose its focus.

Comment: With upsert=True, it does correctly update the document within the array; although it does not create a new one (appending a new element to the array) in case of no matches